# Android/Java: Java: ExceptionInInitializerError caused by NullPointerException when call java.lang.Class.getSimpleName

Tags: java, android, static, nullpointerexception

I got some crash logs on my app.
Following is code from my app project.

```
public class MessageCenter {

     private static final String TAG = MessageCenter.class.getSimpleName();
```

And this is Java library source where the error occurred.

```
    public String getSimpleName() {
    if (isArray()) {
        return getComponentType().getSimpleName() + "[]";
    }

    String name = getName();

    if (isAnonymousClass()) {
        return "";
    }

    if (isMemberClass() || isLocalClass()) {
        return getInnerClassName();
    }

    int dot = name.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (dot != -1) {
        return name.substring(dot + 1);
    }

    return name;
}
```

I don't have any idea why it happened.
That is Java basic API and there is no params.

Also it doesn't really reproduce well and I found it just occurred on 4.1.2 Android OS version. (I'm not sure about other OS version).

Following is the log.

```
03-09 18:24:08.547 W/ImageLoader(19218): memoryCache() and memoryCacheSize() calls overlap each other
03-09 18:24:08.547 W/ImageLoader(19218): diskCache() and diskCacheFileNameGenerator() calls overlap each other
03-09 18:24:08.547 W/ImageLoader(19218): diskCache(), diskCacheSize() and diskCacheFileCount calls overlap each other
03-09 18:24:08.547 W/ImageLoader(19218): diskCache(), diskCacheSize() and diskCacheFileCount calls overlap each other
03-09 18:24:08.547 D/ImageLoader(19218): Initialize ImageLoader with configuration
03-09 18:24:08.547 I/System.out(19218): Couldn't load jnicrash from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.esplanet.lounge-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.esplanet.lounge-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
03-09 18:24:08.547 D/dalvikvm(19218): processAnnotationValue failed on default for 'httpMethod'
03-09 18:24:08.547 D/dalvikvm(19218): processAnnotationValue failed on default for 'reportType'
03-09 18:24:08.557 D/CrashLogger(19218): CrashLogger is enabled for com.esplanet.lounge, intializing...
03-09 18:24:08.557 V/TloungeAppApi(19218): [LoungeAppApi] init(Context context) call
03-09 18:24:08.577 V/TloungeAppApi(19218): [LoungeApi] onServiceConnected = 1
03-09 18:24:08.587 V/TloungeAppApi(19218): [LoungeAppApi] call isMdnLogin
03-09 18:24:08.587 V/TloungeAppApi(19218): isMdnLogin() call
03-09 18:24:08.587 W/dalvikvm(19218): Exception Ljava/lang/NullPointerException; thrown while initializing Lcom/esplanet/pp/sdk/MessageCenter;
03-09 18:24:08.587 D/AndroidRuntime(19218): Shutting down VM
03-09 18:24:08.587 W/dalvikvm(19218): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416bad58)
03-09 18:24:08.587 E/CrashLogger(19218): CrashLogger caught a ExceptionInInitializerError exception for com.esplanet.lounge. Building report.
03-09 18:24:08.587 E/dalvikvm(19218): Invalid debug info stream. class Lcom/esplanet/pp/sdk/MessageCenter;; proto ()V
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218): com.esplanet.lounge fatal error : null
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218):        at com.esplanet.lounge.core.pushmgr.PushManager.initMessageCenter(PushManager.java:275)
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218):        at com.esplanet.lounge.core.pushmgr.PushManager.init(PushManager.java:263)
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218):        at com.esplanet.lounge.core.pushmgr.PushManager.access$8(PushManager.java:262)
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218):        at com.esplanet.lounge.core.pushmgr.PushManager$6.run(PushManager.java:235)
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5090)
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218):        at java.lang.Class.getSimpleName(Class.java:946)
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218):        at com.esplanet.pp.sdk.MessageCenter.<clinit>(MessageCenter.java)
03-09 18:24:08.687 E/CrashLogger(19218):        ... 13 more
03-09 18:24:08.687 I/Process (19218): Sending signal. PID: 19218 SIG: 9
```

If anyone have an idea to avoid exception, please contact me.
Thanks!

Comment: I think there's something wrong in your MessageCenter class. Could you post the entire LogCat (13 more part also)?

Comment: I can't give you entire LogCat (13 more part also). 
Because it isn't reproduced well and auto collected.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
public String getSimpleName() {
    if (isArray()) {
        return getComponentType().getSimpleName() + "[]";
    }
```

is an instance method since there is not static keyword mentioned.You are trying to call the method in a static context i.e. not on an object,this is the reason for your initializer error.
You need an instance of the object before you call this.Try

```
 private static final String TAG = new MessageCenter().getClass().getSimpleName();
```

or if you want to maintain a static reference

```
private static final String TAG = MessageCenter.class.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @Droidekas.
But what is the difference between use getClass() and no use?
Also do you know why it doesn't reproduce 100%?